# Automation of JMeter tests using Maven

Tags: java, maven, automation, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I have included JMeter plugin by lazycode in my application.

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>jmeter-tests</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jmeter</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

This runs when I use `mvn verify`. But, it runs all integration tests and unit tests too. I don't want this to happen. I want to run just `mvn jmeter:jmeter` and run performance tests.

If I run `mvn jmeter:jmeter`, I get

```
No plugin found for prefix 'jmeter' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.sonarsource.scanner.maven, org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories
```

I don't want to configure global `.m2/settings.xml`. How to run it using Maven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, the correct Maven command to run **only** JMeter tests would be:

```
mvn jmeter:jmeter -Pjmeter
```

References:

- [Maven - Introduction to Build Profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)
- [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin)
- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)

Comment: `[WARNING] The requested profile "jmeter" could not be activated because it does not exist.`

Comment: It does not fix the problem with me and adds the same warning @JensPiegsa commented.